# Can I compile Swift code on Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5, swift, xcode6

Xcode 6 beta is still pretty unstable. I was wondering if there is a way to compile Swift from xCode 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are command-line tools available for Swift if the GUI is giving you trouble in Xcode 6. You could call these command-line tools from Xcode 5, I suppose, but Xcode 5 will not be able to do anything smart with Swift, like highlighting, autocompleting or the playground.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on this? For instance, what is the command-line command to compile Swift?

Comment: @pjs The command you are looking for is `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift` which can be used on the command line. For example, you can run `[..]/usr/bin/swift -repl` to get an interactive interpreter.